# From docker file in one container, unable to connect to another container inside the same pod in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-pod

Inside one pod in k8s, I have 2 containers.
Container 1: sqlplus client configured to connect to DB (withDockerAndSqlClientImage)
Container 2: Running DB (OracleDB Image)

In container 1, if I try to connect to DB then it connects to container 2.

```
container('withDockerAndSqlClient') { //part of jenkinsfile
sh "echo checking db connectivity from container"
sh """
    chmod 775 ./checkDBConnection.sh
    ./checkDBConnection.sh  //THIS WORKS 
"""
sh label: "docker build", script: "docker build Dockerfile" //THIS FAILS, WHEN TRY TO CONNECT TO DB FROM DOCKER FILE }
```

when running DB connect script from container 1, it worked. But when running the same script during docker build from container 1, it failed.

DockerFile

```
FROM withDockerAndSqlClientImage: latest
USER root
RUN sqlplus -v 
RUN chmod 744 /usr/src/package/checkDBConnection.sh
RUN /usr/src/package/checkDBConnection.sh  //THIS FAILS, WHEN TRY TO CONNECT TO DB FROM DOCKER FILE
```

checkDBConnection.sh

```
echo "Trying to Connect to DB"
c=1
echo "exit" | sqlplus -L username/pwd@sname | grep Connected > /dev/null
while [[ ("$?" -ne "0")  && ("$c" -le "10") ]]
do
let c=c+1
echo "Retrying to connect to DB...$c"
sleep 10
echo "exit" | sqlplus -L username/pwd@sname | grep Connected > /dev/null
done
```

can somebody please help me with this? I tried to use docker build --network=host in container one .. it did not work.

Comment: A Dockerfile should never connect to a database; if both are running locally in Docker then the connection will always fail.  (What happens if you push the built image to a registry, and then run it on a different system with a different database?)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze . As part of building the image, i have requirement to connect to DB, get some data and zip that data. As part of deploy, i am using that zip data to run on different system.

Comment: Is David's comment enough for you ? Do you need more specification ?